# How can cellular phones be eavesdropped on?

Tags: network, mobile

I know its really stupid question but one of my friend told me that he can listen to the guy who calling on his mobile phone without his phone being the one the call is controlled by.

What ways could this possibly happen?

Comment: Hi Myles - this question is very broad, and not really useful here. There are questions which may cover this off for you - have a look in the related questions bar on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Google Voice allows Call Screening:

```
http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115083
```

"Call screening lets you know who's calling your Google number before you accept the call. It also allows you options on how to handle your calls so that you can choose to accept it, send the caller to voicemail and ***ListenIn***TM, or record the call."